# Run remote debugger with ant script under Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, ant

Is it possible to invoke standard Eclipse remote debugger entry with Ant script?

I want Ant to compile, deploy, then debug.

**UPDATE**

Actually, I have standalone server, which can run in debug mode (this is red5 which is made of something like Tomcat/Jetty). It is runned with `bat` or `sh` script, which runs `JRE` with

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y
```

Usually, to debug an application, I run this shell script and it waits for a debugger.

Then I have `Remote Java Application` launch configuration. When I run it, it connects to previously ran JRE and allows me to trace execution with source code and set breakpoints.

What I want is to AUTOMATE this.

I.e. I would like to have Ant target, which (1) compiles code, (2) deploys it, then (3) runs external application and finally (4) runs eclipse debugger to connect to it.

Points 1-3 are clear, while point 4 is not. I think Eclipse could provide custom Ant task for this.

I.e. I want not to debug Ant script, but debug another code WITH Ant script.

Comment: You want to deploy/run your application in ant and then connect the eclipse debugger to that instance... Correct?

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by adding the java debug options to the `ANT_OPTS` environment variable prior to invoking ant.  If we assume you'd like to use port number 4000...

Unix-based environment:

```
export ANT_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n"
```

Windows-based environment:

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n
```

Comment: This will debug `JRE` which is executing ant script, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, which should allow you to debug the code it is running for you, UNLESS you are calling your code with a target that has `fork="true"`.

Comment: I want Ant script just run Eclipse's remote debugger. Actual debugged application can run on another machine even.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see what you want now, based on your updated post.